# Coffeescript function runs as soon as page is loaded, but I don't want it to do so

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, snap.svg

So I have this function

```
$ ->
  paper = Snap("#svg")
  circ = paper.circle(100, 100, 50)
  circ.click(-> circ.animate({r: 200}, 1000))
```

Which uses the Snap.svg library. It selects an svg element on the page and draws a circle there. When you click the circle the radius increases.

If I wanted to pull out the function inside `circ.click()`, I can't get it to work properly. Either like this

```
$ ->
  foo = (circle) ->
    circ.animate

  paper = Snap("#svg")
  circ = paper.circle(100, 100, 50)
  circ.click(foo(circ))
```

or like this

```
foo = (circ) ->
  circ.animate

$ ->
  paper = Snap("#svg")
  circ = paper.circle(100, 100, 50)
  circ.click(foo(circ))
```

What happens is that `foo()` runs as soon as the page is loaded, but what I want it to do is wait until I click the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. `circ.click(-> foo(circ))`

Comment: That fixed it. Could you explain why that works? I'm not sure why you have to wrap a function call in another function.

Comment: click accepts function as argument to invoke it latter on click event. But in your example you invoke function immideatly. Don't mess with function declaration and function invocation these are two different things.

Answer (score -2):

Each JavaScript file runs as soon as it's loaded. In your original code:

```
$ ->
  ...
```

$ is a method and it's immediately executed, with the following anonymous function passed as argument.

Comment: the defined function is not run with () so it won't be executed as it's loaded

Comment: In Coffee, $ -> ... translates into $(function(){...}), basically a call to $.